# does git reset HEAD^ --hard delete everything?

Tags: git, github, git-reset

I was finished a project, I got a merge conflict, so I stupidly ran `git reset HEAD^ --hard` and now all my files are gone except my node modules folder (which was in .gitignore). Is there anyway I can recover my files?

**I'm using VScode**

Comment: Keyword to google: reflog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As zerkms well said, you haven't lost everything yet, git closely follows what was done, so you can search for your commit via:

`git reflog`

And when you find the one that references your lost work just do

`git reset --hard <commit-ref>`

You can check if your stuff is there by `git show HEAD`

Here is a more in depth guide: http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits